# How to attach lazy function that returns promise to the RxJS pipeline?

Tags: javascript, rxjs

I have a function `lazyFn` that returns a Promise.

I want to attach it to the subject pipeline but invoke it only at the pipeline.

For example if I do that: `withLatestFrom(lazyFn())`, `lazyFn` invokes immediately.

And I have subject pipelines which I trigger by calling `next`:

```
subject.next({ mywork: true });
```

What I try to do is to get the value from `lazyFn` and get the value which emitted to the pipeline (`{ bla: true }`).

But I can't solve it. I expect to get in `tap` function both values: `x = [{lazy: true}, { mywork: true }]`.

I try to use `withLatestFrom` it accepts only observables (not functions).
I try to use `concatMap` but I get only the `lazyFn` part.
I try to use `switchMap` but I get only the `lazyFn` part, and I can't use `pipe` in the inner observable (and I prefer not to because it has nested complex structure).

```
const lazyFn = () => Promise.resolve({ lazy: true });

const subject = new Subject();

const work = subject.pipe(
  withLatestFrom(() => lazyFn()),
  tap((x) => {
    console.log({ x });
  })
);

work.subscribe();

subject.next({ mywork: true });
```

[stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/rxjs-t4mbjg?devtoolsheight=60&file=index.ts)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a combination of a `switchMap` and `combineLatest`.

```
const work = subject.pipe(
  switchMap(x => combineLatest([of(x), lazyFn()])),
  tap((x) => {
    console.log({ x });
  })
);
```

I originally tried with `withLatestFrom` and the `defer` operator but it strangely never emitted.

Comment: When I do `lazyFn()` it invokes immediately right? so that's why I wrap it with a function. and I want to invoke this only when pipeline is running

Comment: If its inside a `switchMap` callback, it should only be invoked *after* the subject emits.